# Are there widely accepted math symbols using non-Latin alphabets or characters other than Greek and Hebrew?

Tags: mathematics, terminology

We have $\pi$ and $\aleph_0$ borrowed from Greek and Hebrew alphabets. Are there widely accepted math symbols using non-Latin alphabets or characters other than Greek and Hebrew?

---

- A related question on Math.SE: [Cyrillic alphabet in math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489136/cyrillic-alphabet-in-math)
- Wikipedia's list of letters used in math and science math symbols
  contains [this list of non-Latin/Greek letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_letters_used_in_mathematics_and_science#More).

Comment: Not "widely accepted" at all, but C. Chevalley's notes on classfield given in Japan use many Japanese symbols...

Comment: Maybe you could change "non-English" to "non-Latin"?

Comment: Wikipedia lists some under [List of letters used in mathematics and science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_letters_used_in_mathematics_and_science#More). Russian Ш (Sh) for the Tate-Shafarevich group and shuffle product, and Japanese よ (Yo) for Yoneda embedding.

Comment: @bmargulies. Did you read the question?

Comment: I can't find it in the Selecta, but I could have sworn that in one of his expository papers ("How to write mathematics" is a natural one, and well worth a (re)read even if it doesn't contain this quote!) Halmos bemoaned the lack of interest in alternative alphabets in mathematics notation.

Comment: @fdb Not very well. Sorry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The letter Ш (sha) of the Cyrillic alphabet is widely accepted in theoretical computer science as the symbol for the *sh*uffle product, which gives the [shuffle algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffle_algebra#Shuffle_product).
The same letter is also used to denote the Tate-Shafarevich group, but I'm not sure if it's really a standard (the letter was introduced by Cassels <del>only in 1990</del> in 1962 instead of TS, see below the KCd's comment).

Sometimes, see for example [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.08870.pdf), the Hiragana symbol よ is used to denote the [Yoneda embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma#The_Yoneda_embedding).

Comment: Nice to know that Japanese characters are involved!!

Comment: The letter Ш was introduced by Cassels *long* before 1990!  He used it in his 1962 Stockholm ICM talk (see p. 238 of https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1962.1/ICM1962.1.ocr.pdf) and in his 1962 paper "Arithmetic on Curves of Genus 1. IV" (Crelle volume 211, see the first page). In his 1962 paper "Arithmetic on curves of genus 1. III" (Proc. LMS volume 12) he used the earlier notation "TS" (essentially), so I think 1962 can be considered the birth year of the Ш notation by Cassels.

Answer (score 11):

There are several non-alphabetic symbols, the best known is the integral sign $\int$
and the Weierstrass $P$-function $\wp$. To be sure their origins are letters of Latin alphabet, but they are special stylized symbols, and as far as I know there is no computer code for them in the standard sets of computer characters. Strictly speaking they do not belong to any alphabet. $\wp$ imitates Weierstrass handwriting. Symbols $\partial$ for the partial derivative and $\infty$ also belong to this list.

There are also mathematicians who use Cyrillic letters, for example John Milnor used Л
for some standard function is hyperbolic geometry, but this can hardly be called
"widely accepted". Л is the first letter in Lobachevski's name (Лобачевский).
I've seen other Cyrillic letters used, but again this is not "widely accepted".

An interesting case is the "letter" $\nabla$ usually used for the gradient. This is a apparently not a letter from any alphabet, and it is called "Nabla" which is the Greek word for some Phoenician musical instrument. See [Nabla symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol). Unlike $\wp$ it is included in Unicode.

Comment: Another widely accepted non-alphabetic symbol is $\sqrt{}$.

Comment: Yes, there are many non-alphabetic symbols, $+,-,=,\sim,\approx,\equiv$ etc. But I suppose that no letter from a real alphabet, other than Latin and Greek, is "widely accepted". Recently I was shown Arabic letters used as math symbols, but only in some countries where people are familiar with them.

Comment: Unicode has ℘ which approximates $\wp$ well enough for many,

Comment: @Jasen why "approximates"? It was intended to be Weierstrass elliptic function, see [here](http://unicode.org/notes/tn27/) (search for `U+2118`). Quoting: _"Should have been called calligraphic small p or Weierstrass elliptic function symbol, which is what it is used for. It is not a capital "P" at all. A formal alias correcting this to WEIERSTRASS ELLIPTIC FUNCTION has been defined."_

Comment: Unicode also has multiple glyphs for integrals, including dedicated ones for multiple integrals and other special forms.

Comment: I think the integral sign is a classical letter S in old English and the square root sign is the radix "r"

Answer (score 11):

It is sometimes asserted that $\varnothing$ for the empty set was introduced by Bourbaki using a Danish and Norwegian letter.

EDIT:

The source is the Weil autobiography, cited [in Jeff Miller's collection](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) of the origins of mathematical expressions:

> André Weil (1906-1998) says in his autobiography that he was responsible for the symbol:
>
> > Wisely, we had decided to publish an installment establishing the system of notation for set theory, rather than wait for the detailed treatment that was to follow: it was high time to fix these notations once and for all, and indeed the ones we proposed, which introduced a number of modifications to the notations previously in use, met with general approval. Much later, my own part in these discussions earned me the respect of my daughter Nicolette, when she learned the symbol Ø for the empty set at school and I told her that I had been personally responsible for its adoption. The symbol came from the Norwegian alphabet, with which I alone among the Bourbaki group was familiar.
>
> The citation above is from page 114 of André Weil's The Apprenticeship of a Mathematician, Birkhaeuser Verlag, Basel-Boston-Berlin, 1992.

Comment: André Weil says in his autobiography that he took $\emptyset$ from ø, having seen it in Norway. Of course, he did not know that the Norwegians got it from Danish.

Answer (score 5):

The cyrillic letter Ш (sha)is -- for obvious reasons when looking at the graph) also used to denote the "function" (well, it is a distribution if you want to be picky) given by the sum of integral displacements of the Dirac-delta function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb

Comment: Yes, it's true, but in this context the letter Ш it's not widely accepted and often it's used (for the same reason) the letter ω (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203030.pdf). Moreover I've noticed that the wikipedia article in English uses **III**, while the Russian one **Δ** !!